# Laravel Auth strange behavior

Tags: php, laravel, authentication, csrf

I have a domain and subdomain based app (all in one Laravel project). I have set up CORS and CSRF so that communication works. I've also replaced the cookie domain under `session.php` and now the session is shared across domain and subdomain.

I have an issue when logging in however. When I log in (either from domain or subdomain) user gets logged in. I can check that by dumping `Auth::user()` under my `web.php`. However when I try to dump it from middleware I get `null`.

How is that possible?

I tried clearing caches on both app and browser

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the issue.

I was calling my middleware before the session middleware under `Kernel.php`

**NOTE**

Global middleware is called before `web` middleware

Answer (score 0):

You should probably check the database, I had those same problems a long time ago.

I think Laravel saves the session in the database, or in some other configuration.

Check "config/session.php"

Hope be helpfull